# How do I remove the last item of an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an array of questions for an interactive quiz game. When you answer a question, functionally I want that question to be removed from the array (cat4Questions) so that it won't come back for the player so I tried to splice it.

I wasn't sure if it was working so I traced the array. While I was expecting "question1, question2, question3, question4" to be traced, "question1, question2, question3, question4, question5" was the result of my trace.

This is the line of code where I try to splice the array:

```
cat4Questions.splice(cat4Questions.length,1);

trace(cat4Questions);
```

Comment: You need to use `cat4Questions.length - 1`, or better yet, use just `-1` to refer to the last element of the array: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000752.html

Comment: Just to summarize, and make it clear for future readers of this (rather wordy) q&a - the answer to the question "How do I remove the last item of an array?" is myArray.pop()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should take a look at [`shift()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#shift%28%29) and [`pop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop%28%29) array methods.

**[`shift()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#shift%28%29)**
Removes the first element from an array and returns that element. The remaining array elements are moved from their original position, i, to i-1.

**[`pop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop%28%29)**
Removes the last element from an array and returns the value of that element.

In your case, you probably need the pop() function to remove the last element of the array.

Comment: `+1` It's advantageous to get your head around using `pop()` in all cases where you need to remove any item from an array (unless it's sorted). Storing the result of `pop()` against a temporary variable and then replacing an item at a given index with it is way, way faster than using `splice()` or most other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are zero-indexed, so you should use `Array.length-1;` to get the index position of the array.

```
cat4Questions.splice(cat4Questions.length-1,1);
trace(cat4Questions);
```

trace now.

Comment: I have discovered that it is more beneficial to use the shift() method on the first item of the array for the functionality I want

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to remove items other than the last item in the array. If for example the user answers another question.

You can use this code to remove any question:

```
cat4Questions.splice(cat4Questions.indexOf(question), 1);
```

**Edit**

As I said in the comments below, you don't really have to look at the performance of this. But here is how to use pop instead of splice.

```
cat4Questions[cat4Questions.indexOf(question)] = cat4Questions.pop();
```

You can also remove the calls to pop and indexOf because they are not efficient either

```
lastQuestion = cat4Questions[--numQuestions];
cat4Questions[question.index] = lastQuestion;
lastQuestion.index = question.index;
```

Where question is the question to be removed, index is the index of the question (you have to keep track of that) and numQuestions is the total number of questions. This way, you never use length, indexOf, pop, splice, ...

Comment: I only recommend using `splice()` when the array in question needs to be ordered.

Comment: Well, I guess his questions have some kind of order. But any way, he is not going to do this operation that many times for it to become an issue. It could be an issue if he was going to remove a 'big' number of items 'every' frame. But here he is only going to remove 'an' item and only a few times in the lifetime of the game. If there are performance issues, it's not here that he should be looking.

Comment: At the same time, I do confirm that arrays have a really terrible performance in flash. Even array.length has a very bad performance. So whenever you are dealing with big arrays and/or doing a lot of operations with them per frame, then you should be very careful with their performance.

Comment: True, but may as well avoid developing a habit of using it when it often can be a massive reason for the loss of performance.